# Not sure how to solve this limit problem

Tags: limits

$$ \lim_{(x, y)\to (0,0)} \frac{\cos(x) - 1 + \frac{x^2}{2}}{x^4+y^4}$$

The limit doesn't exist, but I am not sure how to proceed with that $\cos(x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Along the $y$ axis the limit is $0$. Use Taylor expansion of $\cos x $ to show that the limit along the $x$ axis is $\frac  1 {24}$. Hence the limit does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{\cos(x)-1+\frac{x^2}2}{x^4+y^4}=\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{\cos(x)-1+\frac{x^2}2}{x^4}\times\frac{x^4}{x^4+y^4}.$$